# Transfer files from flash,iphone,android device to LAMP server

Tags: file-upload, lamp

I have a LAMP server that needs to accept files from flash applications that run locally on client's computer (ie, they open the swf file from their windows explorer), iphone apps and android apps.

My understanding is that I need to set up a webservice on my LAMP server to allow for this.  Basically I create a PHP file that's accessible via `http://mysite.com/upload.php`, and it accepts _POST data.  The POST data will contain the file the client application sends me.

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully implemented the approach above.  I posted a queston about Curl equivalent for Android here.

[What is android's equivalent for this curl operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279151/what-is-androids-equivalent-for-this-curl-operation)

So now other client devices can do the same.